# Ledger Nano and MEW

Tags: hardware-wallets

Trying to connect MEW to Ledger Nano but my address will not come up when I try to add it to the ledger.
Really stumped with this one.
Appreciate any help. Using Mac laptop with google chrome

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried navigating to **Settings** in your Ledger and setting the **Browser Support** to **"Yes"**?

*This is usually set to "No" by default.*

Comment: I want to add an existing mew to my new ledger nano is this possible? or do I have to open new mew on ledger and transfer? Of course this means I will have expenses to transfer (send)

Comment: There are ways to “restore” an account on Ledger from and existing seed word (https://medium.com/@trionkidnapper/ledger-nano-s-restoring-a-device-using-recovery-phrase-d80051ecf17a). However, for security purposes, I suggest you set up your Ledger as a new account as outlined here (https://medium.com/@trionkidnapper/ledger-nano-s-configuring-a-new-device-912b47608ca6) and then simply send those existing funds from your MEW account to your new Ledger address.

Comment: The cost of transferring Ether is negligible (usually less than $0.1) so transferring to a new secure account would be well worth it.